# Bash filename expansion identifies items in file tree, called command not

Tags: bash, filenames, expansion

```
..poky/build$ for SUBPATH in $(bitbake -e alsa-lib | grep -P -e '(?<=^)FILES_alsa-lib(?==)'  | cut -d= -f2 | tr -d \") ; do ls ./tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/package$SUBPATH 2>&1 ; done | grep  -e "No such file or directory" | wc -l
2855
..poky/build$ for SUBPATH in $(bitbake -e alsa-lib | grep -P -e '(?<=^)FILES_alsa-lib(?==)'  | cut -d= -f2 | tr -d \") ; do ls ./tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/package$SUBPATH 2>&1 ; done | grep -v -e "No such file or directory" | wc -l
15
```

Here one of all those No such file or directory

```
ls: cannot access ./tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/package/usr/lib/libicalss.so.1.0.0: No such file or directory
```

where

```
..poky/build$ bitbake -e alsa-lib | grep -P -e '(?<=^)FILES_alsa-lib(?==)'  | cut -d= -f2 | tr -d \"
/usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/* /usr/lib/alsa-lib/* /usr/lib/lib*.so.* /etc /com /var /bin/* /sbin/* /lib/*.so.* /lib/udev/rules.d /usr/lib/udev/rules.d /usr/share/alsa-lib /usr/lib/alsa-lib/* /usr/share/pixmaps /usr/share/applications /usr/share/idl /usr/share/omf /usr/share/sounds /usr/lib/bonobo/servers /usr/lib/alsa-lib/smixer/*.so
```

and

```
poky/build$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Apparently Bash file name expansion finds 2855 items in identified sub-paths the called ls command can't identify.
Actually in every iteration instead of `ls ...` I need to do `find` with search root point set to `./tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/package$SUBPATH` and `-name`argument set few times (logical OR) to some patterns.

Where is my mistake?
Is this that file name expansion takes place in the for-loop instead of on invoking ls command (as programmer wishes it)?

### #

Following alternative found under my limited expertise level and time resources

```
cd ./tmp-glibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/package &&  echo "/usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/* /usr/lib/alsa-lib/* /usr/lib/lib*.so.* /etc /com /var /bin/* /sbin/* /lib/*.so.* /lib/udev/rules.d /usr/lib/udev/rules.d /usr/share/alsa-lib /usr/lib/alsa-lib/* /usr/share/pixmaps /usr/share/applications /usr/share/idl /usr/share/omf /usr/share/sounds /usr/lib/bonobo/servers"      | sed -r 's/(^\/)/.\//g' | sed -r 's/( \/)/ .\//g'  | ls -Ralh $(awk '{print $0}') ; cd -
```

Glue for pasting long string with sub-paths to this command pipe from building block presented earlier out of scope as for this Q.

If possible please review. Thanks.
Does this qualify to be this Q's answer?

Comment: Avoid `for x in $()`, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: Thanks for highly valuable hint. Based on this my new plan is to use string with sub-paths listed literally in pipe of xargs and find.

Comment: Same problem with `bitbake -e alsa-lib | grep -P -e '(?<=^)FILES_alsa-lib(?==)' | cut -d= -f2 | tr -d \"  | sed -r 's/(^\/)//g' | sed -r 's/( \/)/ /g' | awk '{print $0," ( -name \"*so.*\" -o -name \"*.a\" -o -name \"*.la\" ) -o ( -perm u=x -o -perm g=x -o -perm o=x )  -type f"}'  | xargs find`.   It's true several are not existing, however at least `/usr/lib/lib*.so.*` should resolve to few .so files. `"find: usr/lib/lib*.so.*: No such file or directory"` instead produced by this sequence.